# Saved plot legend box does not display one of the lines

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I am plotting in Matlab and saving it as a jpeg image. The problem is that the saved image is not showing the complete box (This just happen if I put the box outside of the plot space). This is the code I am using an I have not any error displayed. Any suggestions??. thanks.

```
fig1 = figure;
plot(n6C(:,1),n6C(:,2),'o-','MarkerIndices',1:10:length(n6C))
hold on
plot(n6(:,1),n6(:,2),'*-','MarkerIndices',1:10:length(n6C))
hold on
plot(n6B(:,1),n6B(:,2),'v-','MarkerIndices',1:10:length(n6C))
hold off
legend('Test 0.5mm','Test 2mm','Test 3mm','location','northeastoutside')
grid on
title('Wind velocity');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Velocity (m/s)');
saveas(fig1,'Vel.jpeg')
```

The plot generated:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a lot of issues like this with `saveas` in the past. If you have version R2020a I would suggest using `exportgraphics` instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I saved in pdf and that also worked. But also Irealized that if I put more than 3 legends or less it made the square properly, I imagine is a kind of bug?